# Extract different percentages/numbers from a paragraph/string in r

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm a novice in R and am struggling with extracting percentages/numbers from strings in a data frame. For example,

```
df <- data.frame(
  Species =c("Bidens pilosa","Orobanche ramose"),
  Impact = c("Soyabean yield loss was 10%. A density of one plant resulted in a yield loss of 9.4%; two plants, 17.3%; and four to eight plants, 28%...In contrast, suppression of the weed by the crop was only 10%","Cypress was estimated to have a 28% loss annually. The annual increase of the disease in some stands in the Peloponnesus, with an initial attack of 20%, ranged from 5% to 20% ")
```

My questions are the following:

1. In this case, I only want to extract yield loss for different crops, which is 10 and 28, and hope to skip percentages and numbers regarding other aspects (such as 9.4%,17.3%, 5* etc.) Can I achieve this objective through R? Or it requires some skill about natural language processing?
2. If it's hard to distinguish different types of percentages, how to extract all percentages/numbers at one time so that I can pick the right number manually. I have tried to use

```
df %>% str_match_all("[0-9]+") %>% unlist %>% as.numeric
```

or

```
parse_number(df$Impact)
```

But I think none of them works, because they give me continuous lines of numbers.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1) There is no clear pattern on how to extract yield loss. In the first string itself, I see "yield loss" mention twice.

> Soyabean yield loss was 10%. A density of one plant resulted in a yield loss of 9.4%;

So why one should select 10 and not 9.4 is not clear at least to me.

2) To extract all the percentages/numbers you can use :

```
stringr::str_extract_all(df$Impact, "\\d+\\.?\\d?")

#[[1]]
#[1] "10"   "9.4"  "17.3" "28"   "10"  

#[[2]]
#[1] "28" "20" "5"  "20"
```

which is equivalent to

```
regmatches(df$Impact, gregexpr("\\d+\\.?\\d?", df$Impact))
```

in base R.

`\\d+` means 1 or more than 1 digits

`\\.?`  is an optional decimal place

`\\d?` is an optional digit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'm quite confused about what does "\\d+\\.?\\d?" represent?

Comment: @Vivi Updated the answer explaining that. See if that helps.